# AngularJS controller does not do its job

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is the thing: I am trying to learn AngularJS and making a very simple thing so far.

app.js

```
(function () {
'use strict';
angular.module('vApp', []);
})();
```

ListUsersController.js

```
(function () {
'use strict';

var app= angular.module('vApp');

app.controller('Hello', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.id = 'ID';
    $scope.content = 'some stuff';
}]);

}());
```

hello.jsp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<html ng-app="vApp">
<head>
<title>Spring 3 MVC Series - Contact Manager</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="WEB-INF/angular/app.js"></script>
<script src="WEB-INF/angular/ListUsersController.js"></script>

</head>
<body >


<div ng-controller="Hello">
<h1>Supposed to be cool</h1>
<p>The ID is {{id}}</p>
<p>The content is {{content}}</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

and seems like I am doing a completely stupid mistake somewhere as I get this in my browser :

> Supposed to be cool
>
> The ID is {{id}}
>
> The content is {{content}}

No matter what I try and how I change the code, nothing works. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?
Any hint would be appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

**EDIT**
 Since it is most probable that the problem is caused by script files not found exception I have decided to input my web app structure, because this problem does not make any sense:

```
-webapp
-WEB-INF
    -angular
        app.js
        ListUsersController.js
    -pages
        hello.jsp
```

Comment: You don't need to wrap controller and module declaration inside (function () {..Remove that snippet and it will work

Comment: This wrapping is considered a very good practice because it will isolate the local scope from the external one. It will avoid scope pollution so I would recommend you keep it.

Comment: However you should move the last () , see my answer for more details

Answer (score 1):

I have copied exactly your HTML and JS code to save locally. Then I did not use JSP, simply open the HTML file in the browser, it works! The result is fine as:

```
Supposed to be cool

The ID is ID

The content is some stuff
```

I suspect you did not include the JS files correctly, i.e.:

```
<script src="WEB-INF/angular/app.js"></script>
<script src="WEB-INF/angular/ListUsersController.js"></script>
```

Please check them.

---

Before you configure your app to a server, say, Apache, your files are just local files and located through either absolute or relative paths. But for web server software, you need to define your own URL mapping rules. Say: http://book.seaside.st/book/advanced/deployment/deployment-apache/serving-files

Comment: Thank you. Yes, you have the right, the app returns Not Found 404 for the script files, though in the editor it is completely fine and it finds files with autocompliting. Any suggestion why it could be so?

Comment: Before you configure your app to a server, say, Apache, your files are just local files and located through either absolute or relative paths. But for web server software, you need to define your own URL mapping rules. Say: http://book.seaside.st/book/advanced/deployment/deployment-apache/serving-files

Comment: I am not sure if I understand what you mean by this, as I am using Apache Tomcat and it is not supposed to be that complicated. everything should work by itself. But thanx for the answer anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Putting the code in an autoexecuted function is very good practice, except that you did a small mistake.

Move the last () outside of the function and other braces.

```
(function () {
'use strict';

var app= angular.module('vApp');

app.controller('Hello', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.id = 'ID';
    $scope.content = 'some stuff';
}]);

})();
```

Otherwise the function is never called and your code doesn't "exist" for the browser.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I assume that is one of the problems, as I have changed it and still it does not work because of wrong script path in the jsp file

Comment: did you check the final structure that is generated for the javascript file when you display the page in the browser ? check the ressources. You may find something unexpected

Comment: @sam It is not even a mistake. Check out Ben Alman's blog: http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/

Answer (score 0):

from where you got that syntax: -
    (function () {
    'use strict';

```
var app= angular.module('vApp');
..
..
}());
```

just remove (function () {
            'use strict'; and last respectively braces.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is: Dependency Injection.
You have to it this way. 
In Your app.js

```
    angular.module('vApp', ['vApp.controller']);
```

ListUsersController.js

```
angular.module('vApp.controller',[])
   .controller('Hello', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.id = 'ID';
    $scope.content = 'some stuff';
}]);
```

Comment: What are you trying to convey ??